# python numba: using nopython for a function receiving a function as argument

Tags: python, numba, jit

Trying to use `numba` to jit my code using the `nopython=True` flag, I get an error for functions which receive a function as argument:

```
import numba
import numpy as np      
 
x = np.random.randn(10,10)     
f = lambda x : (x>0)*x

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def a(x,f): return f(x)**2+x

a(x,f)
```

The error message received is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type pyobject
During: typing of argument at <stdin> (2)

File "<stdin>", line 2:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 1: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
```

Ommiting the `nopython` flag does work:

```
@numba.jit
def a(x,f): return f(x)**2+x

a(x,f)
```

Can I somehow annotate the code or differently define `f` in order to inform `numba` of its type?

Comment: As an aside, in python parlance, that is just a *function*. Not a "function handle"

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure about this, but I think numba will only handle other numba functions correctly, at least, that is what the examples seem to imply in the [docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#functions-as-arguments)

Comment: I don't think numba can compile function, which accepts arbitrary function as an argument. I am not even sure that it can compile it with other jitted function. Numba has a very limited scope. So it tries to fallback to object mode. Nopython does not allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot provide a pure-Python function which is not compiled with Numba to a Numba code executing it in nopython mode. If you really want to do that, you need to use the `objmode` switch which is experimental and inefficient (so it is not very useful except in very few special cases). The typical solution is simply to **compile the function** so Numba can call it from a nopython mode:

```py
import numba
import numpy as np      
 
x = np.random.randn(10,10)   
  
@numba.njit
def f(x):
    return (x>0)*x

@numba.njit
def a(x,f):
    return f(x)**2+x

a(x,f)
```